# How i can close first form and invoke second form in c#

Tags: c#

the form1 remains open and form2(main) is opened but when i close first one the second also closes

```
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.Hide();

        Main main = new Main();
        main.Show();

        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void  Proc()
{
    Form2 Child; 
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Proc));
    t.Start();
    this.Close();
 }
```

Comment: You are confusing me, finally can you try this!

Answer (score 1):

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form at run time by handling the **Closing** event and setting the **Cancel** property of the **CancelEventArgs** passed as a parameter to your event handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your application, your application ends.

From [Form.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Remarks

When you close the parent form, any child forms die with it. You can inherit from [ApplicationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override the form's [closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change the behaviour of closing Forms. You may also be able to change the Form's Parent and ParentForm properties to change this behaviour. You may also want to consider simply hiding your form instead of closing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ShowDialog, Try this:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: it works but when i close the second form it opens the first again